# CakePHP Cron Job on GoDaddy

Tags: cakephp, cron, cakephp-2.0, shared-hosting

I am hosted on GoDaddy Shared server. And i would like to run a cron job to send daily emails. Since i dont have access to the shell. Is there any way i can run the cron job to send the email ?

Comment: Hello. Did you double-check with GD that you cannot access the shell? I did work for a client recently who has GD Shared server and we were able to access the shell.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss can you tell how to i can do that ?

Comment: Hello. The client provided SSH information. I think you should just email GD and double-check. It is always possible the client had a different server than he told me. They often are a bit oblivious to these terms. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Go Daddy shared hosting you can create a cron job using the Hosting Control Center.

To Create a Cron Job

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click Web Hosting.
3. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Launch.
4. In the Content section of the Hosting Control Center, click the Cron Job Manager icon. This action displays the Cron Job Manager screen.
5. Click edit next to the Email Address heading in the left navigation area.
6. Enter the email address to which you would like to have all information sent regarding this Cron Job.
7. Click Save.
8. Click Create Cron Job.
9. Click Custom.
10. Enter the required information in each field to schedule the task to run repeatedly at specific intervals.

    Cron Job Title

    Enter a name for this Cron Job. Ideally, this title relates to this task, so you can identify it easily.

    Command

    The Command field is the script or executable that runs at a specified frequency. Click Browse to locate a file in your hosting account. The full file name of your selection is placed into this editable field. Click the question mark icon for additional assistance in selecting a command.

    NOTE: Our sample scripts use the variable $HOME. We recommend using $HOME to represent the actual server path, although either can be used.

    Minutes

    Enter the time that you want the Cron Job to run. For example, you can set your job to run at 15 minutes after each hour by selecting "x:15." You can run tasks twice per hour by selecting the Run twice an hour setting. This setting automatically sets tasks to run 30 minutes apart.

    Hours

    Enter the time of day that you want the Cron Job to run. For example, you can set your job to run each day at 1:00 p.m. by selecting "13:xx."

    Day of the Month

    Enter the day of the month that you want the Cron Job to run. For example, you can set your job to run on the 15th of each month by selecting "15."

    Month

    Enter the month that you want the Cron Job to run. For example, you can set your job to run each February by selecting "February."

    Day of the Week

    Enter the day of the week that you want the Cron Job to run. For example, you can set your job to run each Thursday by selecting "Thursday."
11. Click Save.

Your Cron Job is saved, enabled, and runs at the next scheduled interval.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler solution that doesn't require hacking core files. Just use this for your cron job:

```
/web/cgi-bin/php5 -q -d register_argc_argv=on $HOME/html/lib/Cake/Console/cake.php -app $HOME/html/app your_shell -q
```